# Problema com lista suspensa em cascata

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

## Contextualização

Estou tentando criar uma lista suspensa para as células da coluna Modelo, que depende do valor da célula correspondente na coluna Fabricante.
[image: Plan2]

A tabela acima está na aba **Plan2**

No arquivo há uma aba com a relação de fabricante e modelo
[image: Plan1]

A tabela acima está na aba **Plan1**

A partir da aba de fabricantes e modelos, eu criei os intervalos nomeados abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Problema

Estou fazendo a validação para as células da coluna Modelo (aba Plan2)da seguinte forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A referência A2, no caso acima, terá o valor "Fiat", que é um dos intervalos nomeados da planilha.

Quando faço dessa forma, a lista suspensa não fica com nenhum valor. Entretanto, se eu definir um intervalo nomeado estático, selecionando os modelos abaixo do fabricante e nomeando o intervalo selecionado, a lista suspensa é preenchida perfeitamente.

Já verifiquei se a fórmula com o DESLOC está referenciando o intervalo correto e está tudo OK.

Cheguei a seguinte conclusão: a fórmula INDIRETO não força o cálculo da função que define o intervalo nomeado, neste caso a função DESLOC. Percebi isso ao realizar um teste para montar uma lista suspensa com os nomes das colunas da tabela abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A função que utilizei foi INDIRETO("Teste")

Ao auditar a fórmula, clicando na barra de fórmula e apertando CRTL + SHIFT + ENTER (trata-se de uma função matricial), a função INDIRETO com o Teste estático me retornou o vetor de valores correto, enquanto que com o Teste dinâmico, me retornou #REF, ou seja, houve algum erro.

Comment: Excelente pergunta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certo! Uma das soluções que utilizo para essa *seleção condicional* seria assim:

1. Crio duas tabela com meus dados utilizando o recurso de [tabela pré-formatada do Excel](http://excelguru.com.br/excel-2/tabelas/), que ficaria algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Claro que há a possibilidade de manter sua tabela com o fabricante no cabeçalho também... mas acho mais fácil e práticos dessa forma, caso possa alterar o padrão atual, em função do Excel expandir as seleções ao inserir novos dados.

2. Defino os nomes de cada lista de dados

   - Modelos:
     [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
   - Coluna que será pesquisada:
     [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
3. Insere a pesquisa na tabela desejada

Para isso teremos os seguintes passos:

1. Selecione a coluna onde gostaria de ter a lista suspensa condicional (somente os dados pré-selecionados)
2. Adicione uma validação de dados
3. Permita entrada de Listas do Excel
4. Coloque a fórmula: `=DESLOC(modelos;CORRESP($A2;pesquisa_fabricante;0)-1;0;CONT.SE(pesquisa_fabricante;$A2))`

Conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em resumo a validação vai deslocar o número de linhas correspondentes à seleção que está em "D4". Contudo, como colocamos o marcador `$`, o Excel expande para toda nossa coluna. Caso esteja usando [tabela pré-formatada](http://excelguru.com.br/excel-2/tabelas/), ao inserir novas colunas (e não somente as selecionadas) o Excel já atualiza a validação de dados na nova linha.

**Na sua tabela seria `A2` conforme a imagem que publicou.**

> Dependendo da versão do Excel que você utiliza será necessário substituir os nomes das listas (`modelos` e `pesquisa_fabricante`) pelos endereços dos dados (`modelos=$B$2:$B$5` e `pesquisa_fabricante=$A$2:$A$5`)

Espero ter ajudado!